# How to deserialize a generic type with jackson?

Tags: java, generics, jackson, deserialization

I tried many solutions, but my case seems special. The `@JsonProperty` must be depending on class type:

I have JSON for two entities:

> "Person": [       {           "id": "452009517701",           "name": "Perosn1",
>             "address": "541-DPL-355"        } ]
>
> "Car": [      {           "id": 5787544,          "brand": "Toyota",          "number":
>   12454         } ]

The entities look like :

```
public class Person{
    private String id:
    private String name;
    private String address:
    // Constcutors && Getters && Setters
}

public class Car{
    private Long id:
    private String brand;
    private Long number:
    // Constcutors && Getters && Setters
}
```

The generic class :

```
public class GenericEntity<T>{
    //@JsonProperty
    private List<T> myList;
    // Constcutors && Getters && Setters
}
```

Main class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        GenericEntity p=mapper.readValue(personJson,GenericEntity.class);
        GenericEntity c=mapper.readValue(carJson,GenericEntity.class);
    }
```

When I debug I find that the lists inside GenericEntity are always null. I do not know how to set jsonProperty dynamically on the top of the list inside the `GenericEntity`.

Also, i used :

```
Object readValue = mapper.readValue(jsonPerson, new TypeReference<GenericEntity<Person>>() {});
```

And :

```
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(GenericEntity.class, Person.class);
        Object readValue =mapper.readValue(jsonPerson, javaType);
```

Bu i got this :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.GenericEntity` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Person')
 at [Source: (String)""Person": [ { "id": "452009517701", "name": "Perosn1", "address": "541-DPL-355" } ]"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1032)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a single `GenericEntity` will always have array of either `Car` or `Person`, but never `Car`s and `Person`s mixed?

Comment: GenericEntity will always have array of either Car or Person and never mixted

Comment: do you have more types than `Car` and `Person`, will it vary?

Comment: May be in future i will create other entities

Comment: Then the easiest would be to create `class GenericEntity { @JsonProperty("Car") List<Car> car; @JsonProperty("Person") List<Person> person; }` and check that in a runtime. The other solution requires writing custom deserializer for `GenericEntity` class - this way you will have a full control of how object is being deserialized

Comment: I can only have one at a time, i mean if you see at  the example above , you will find that i I deserialize separately the two jsons (Person, Car)

Comment: That's right, one of those fields will always be null

Comment: ok :) i am going to test  that

Comment: Please also note that this `json` is not valid (it should have curly braces `{}` around it. e.g. `{ "Car": [ { "id": 5787544, "brand": "Toyota", "number": 12454 } ] }`

Comment: Could you just summarize all what did you propose in a response to close the post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use a wrapper type with a separate field per collection type, like that:

```
class GenericEntity {
    @JsonProperty("Car") List<Car> car; 
    @JsonProperty("Person") List<Person> person; 
}
```

This way you would always have one of those lists filled (according to our conversation in comments). This will work fine as long as you don't have too many types and it doesn't change too frequently :)

The more-advanced way would be to use a custom deserializer, like that:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
class GenericEntity<T> {
    List<T> myList;

    GenericEntity(List<T> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }
}
```

The deserializer itself would have to create a `GenericEntity` on its own, but it can delegate all specific-type-deserializing job to other deserializers (so our job would be just to tell it what to deserialize and to what type):

```
class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<GenericEntity<?>> {

    @Override
    public GenericEntity<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);
        if (node.hasNonNull("Person")) {
            JsonParser nodeParser = node.get("Person").traverse(codec);
            nodeParser.nextToken();
            Person[] people = ctxt.readValue(nodeParser, Person[].class);
            return new GenericEntity<>(asList(people));
        } else if (node.hasNonNull("Car")) {
            JsonParser nodeParser = node.get("Car").traverse(codec);
            nodeParser.nextToken();
            Car[] cars = ctxt.readValue(nodeParser, Car[].class);
            return new GenericEntity<>(asList(cars));
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find a type to deserialize!");
    }
}
```